# Cypher - Depth Relationship does not take direction into account?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, depth

It seems like the depth relationships do not take into account the direction I specify. See image for example:

[image: Neo4j screenshot]

**Query:**

```
MATCH (p)-[r:accessRole|:isMemberOf*1..5]->(n:part {_id: "d4a77790-eb40-11e9-86a3-cd3a4d171bfc"}) WHERE (p:PermissionSet OR p:Group) RETURN n,r,p
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was going through a user node with the same relationship name, so it worked with this:

```
MATCH path = (p)-[r:accessRole|:isMemberOf*1..10]->(n:${nodetypeName} {_id: "${nodeId}"})
WHERE ((p:PermissionSet OR p:Group) AND NONE(node in NODES(path) WHERE "user" IN labels(node)))
RETURN DISTINCT p
```